# What are good packages to schedule jobs in express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, job-scheduler

Coming from a rails background where DelayedJob/sidekiq integrate very simply with the Rails application, I am a little unsure about how to do the same with Express. I found [bull](https://github.com/OptimalBits/bull) in a few examples with node, but I am unsure about the right app structure/convention.

What I am trying to achieve is picking up datetimes from a file and on those values execute a particular function. I thought a cron job/scheduler would be a good way to implement this, but I am open to suggestions!

Would love to know the right way [in terms of packages and project structure] to do this in express!

Comment: Lots of choices here: https://www.google.com/search?q=npm+cron depending upon your specific needs.